# Filter Columns using JDBC Query as a data source with the view panel in xpages

Tags: xpages

I am trying to pull the records from SQL using JDBC Query as a datasource and displaying these records with the view panel available using xpages. Now, I have a requirement of filter the values of 6 columns from the records display using JDBC query and display the values based on filter.
I knew that we can implement this using data view if the source is domino view. But here I am using JDBC Query to pull SQL records to show using notes view panel in xpages and I am not sure to filter the data based on column values.
So, could any one help on this would be a great help?

Answer (score 0):

The xe:jdbcQuery has an sqlQuery property and sqlParameters which can be used to filter the result set from the table.  For example,

```
    <xp:viewPanel rows="12" id="viewPanel1" var="row">
        <xp:this.data>
            <xe:jdbcQuery sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE REGION LIKE ?"
                calculateCount="true" var="jdbcQuery1" connectionManager="jdbcConnectionManager1">
                <xe:this.sqlParameters>
                    <xe:sqlParameter>
                        <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return (!!viewScope.region) ? viewScope.region : "%";}]]></xe:this.value>
                    </xe:sqlParameter>
                </xe:this.sqlParameters>
            </xe:jdbcQuery>
        </xp:this.data>
```